# Grouped cross-product in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to do the FP equivalent of (pseudocode):

```
var l1 = [ '1', '2', '3' ];
var l2 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];

var table = []
for i in l1 {
   var row = [];
   for j in l2 {
      row.push([i, j]);
   }
   table.push(row);
}
```

Resulting in `table ==`:

```
[
   [["1", "a"], ["1", "b"], ["1", "c"]], 
   [["2", "a"], ["2", "b"], ["2", "c"]], 
   [["3", "a"], ["3", "b"], ["3", "c"]]
]
```

I have achieved this with:

```
const headEquals = (x,y) => R.equals(R.head(x), R.head(y));

const transform = R.compose(
   R.groupWith(headEquals),
   R.xprod
);

const table = transform(l1,l2);
```

... but it feels inelegant - the intermediate data structure produced by `xprod` is discarding structure from the input, which we then recalculate by doing lots of `equals` comparisons.

What's a better way to achieve this in Ramda?

Comment: The cleanest way you are going to do this (IMO) is without ramda: `const transform = (l1, l2) => l1.map(i => l2.map(j => [i, j]))`. Otherwise you are going to be doing extra work or writing something really verbose. I'm happy to be proven wrong though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
R.map(R.xprod(__, l2), l1)
```

http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20l1%20%3D%20%5B%20%271%27%2C%20%272%27%2C%20%273%27%20%5D%3B%0Avar%20l2%20%3D%20%5B%20%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%20%5D%3B%0A%0AR.map%28R.xprod%28__%2C%20l2%29%2C%20l1%29

Another way

```
R.splitEvery(l2.length, R.xprod(l1, l2))
```

Comment: And I was going to answer that there was not likely anything more concise, as this is traditionally the way that Ramda works!  That'll teach me!  Note that this still creates the intermediate container...

Comment: That should be `R.splitEvery(l2.length, R.xprod(l1, l2))`.  (split on the length of the second array.)  Use `[1, 2, 3]` and `['a', 'b']` to show the difference.